# Percentage revenue calculation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I have a column of costs in a pandas dataframe. If the cost is more than 10, the percentage we get from that sale is 20%. If it is less than 10, then the percentage we get is 15%. How can I calculate the total revenue (from these percentages we got) for the whole column?

cost_of_order

- 4$
- 7$
- 15$
- 20$
- 3$

Output must be 0.6 + 1.05 +3 + 4 + 0.45 = 9.1

Comment: Please provide a sample input dataframe and sample dataframe containing expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the map function to apply a short lambda function for the conditionals.

```
#this creates the percentage column, not sure if you want this  
df['percentage'] = df['cost_of_order'].map(lambda x: x*0.15 if x < 10 else x*0.2)

#this returns the 9.1 as you wanted. 
df['percentage'].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can use else if for lambda format? For example if it is less than 10 lambda is x*0.15 and more than 10 is x*0.2 in its current form. If I want to add: "ELSE if it is more than 20 x must be x*0.30"

Comment: In general, I believe lambdas does not accept elifs by default. However, you could 'bypass' this by putting a new IF statement inside the else statement. 

**lambda x: condition_1 else (condition_2 else ....)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```
# Setup: df = pd.DataFrame({'cost_of_order': ['4$', '7$', '15$', '20$', '3$']})

# If needed, remove '$' then convert to numeric
df['cost_of_order'] = pd.to_numeric(df['cost_of_order'].str.rstrip('$'))

pct = pd.cut(df['cost_of_order'].tolist(),
             bins=[0, 10, 20, np.nan],
             labels=['0.15', '0.2', '0.3']).astype(float)

out = df['cost_of_order'].mul(pct).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
9.1
```